# Facebook Publishing Score

Tags: facebook

I am trying to publish scores from my app. But unfortunately I am unable to do so. I even tried using the code snippet at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/ but for some odd reason it didn't work for me. If someone can provide me with some basic guidelines I would really be helpful as that would help me build upon that system and move forward. I don't want any fancy publishing technique I am just looking forward to publishing score at the end of the game.

Using https://graph.facebook.com/user id/scores?score=10&access_token=acess_token returns

{
   "data": [

]
}

Comment: "*didn't* work for me" isn't really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example looks like a HTTP GET request (i.e. 'show me the scores of this user')

To update a score you either need to make a POST request, or 'fake' the POST request by adding `?method=post` to your GET call

You'll also need to use an App Access Token, the instructions for obtaining this are at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin

Comment: Ok well thats a shot in the right direction! But now how do i retrieve the app access token?

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot!!!! If i need any further help while putting it into a php file i shall bug you again and once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using javascript sdk, you can check out the source code for my game
https://apps.facebook.com/tgif-game/
you should be checking out scripts/gameui.js for the calls to posting scores and getting the list of scores.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it is all encrypted!

Answer (score 0):

In the FaceBook Developer Dashboard set your app category as games.
Then only you'll be able to post scores.